# Ajax loop WordPress Posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to apply this tutorial on my website

[Getting Loopy - Ajax Powered Loops with jQuery and WordPress](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress--wp-23232)

[DEMO](http://www.dzlng.com/demo)

I applied everything and I'm getting this error from Chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This my code:

```
// ajaxLoop.js
jQuery(function($){
    var page = 1;
    var loading = true;
    var $window = $(window);
    var $content = $("#articles-wrapper");
    var load_posts = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type       : "GET",
                data       : {numPosts : 5, pageNumber: page}, 
                dataType   : "html",
                url        : "http://www.dzlng.com/demo/wp-content/themes/dzlng/loopHandler.php",
                beforeSend : function(){
                    if(page != 1){
                       /* $content.append('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center">\
                            loading....\
                            </div>');*/
                    }
                },
                success    : function(html){
                    $data = $(html);
                    if($data.length){
                        //$data.hide();
                        var newItems = $(html).appendTo($("#articles-wrapper"));
                        imagesLoaded('#articles-wrapper', function() {
                            $("#articles-wrapper").isotope('appended', newItems );
                        });
                        $data.fadeIn(500, function(){
                            $("#temp_load").remove();
                            loading = false;
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("#temp_load").remove();
                    }
                },
                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#temp_load").remove();
                    alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                }
        });
    }
    $window.scroll(function() {
        var content_offset = $content.offset();
        //console.log(content_offset.top);
        if(!loading && ($window.scrollTop() +
            $window.height()) > ($content.scrollTop() + $content.height() + content_offset.top)) {
                loading = true;
                page++;
                load_posts();
        }
    });
    load_posts();
});
```

And:

```
<?php
//loopHandler.php
// Our include
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

// Our variables
$numPosts = (isset($_GET['numPosts'])) ? $_GET['numPosts'] : 0;
$page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

query_posts(array(
       'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
       'paged'          => $page
));

// our loop
if (have_posts()) {
       while (have_posts()){
              the_post();
              get_template_part( 'content', 'item' );
       }
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I tried few stuff but it's not working.

Comment: Is `imagesLoaded` a function? Can't see the function definition here. Otherwise is there a line number to point you to the error? This is a JS error that will come about when you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist - either it hasn't been declared, it's in a different scope / inaccessible, or could be mistyped?

Comment: It looks like it's the `isotope()` function that's undefined.  Does it help if you add a dependency on `isotope.pkgd.min.js` when you enqueue `ajaxLoop.js`?

Comment: You need to call `$("#articles-wrapper").isotope()` before you append elements.

Comment: in wp-config.php turn on debug mode like define('WP_DEBUG', true); and then check for errors.

Comment: You're PHP doesn't return images .. how content-item.php looks like ?